# Customize the value of struts2 textfield tag using OGNL

Tags: java, struts2, ognl

I have a database with a user information. When the user is logged on, I registered the user on the session as follow:

```
ActionContext.getContext().getSession().put("loggedUser", user);
```

And I want to get the user's information in my jsp page to fill the struts2 textfields with this info. I tried to use the following code, but it does not work:

```
<%@page import="java.util.Map"%>
<%@page import="com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="UbiMail.*" %>
<%@taglib  prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<%

        User user = (User) ActionContext.getContext().getSession().get("LoggedUser");
%>

<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

    <s:form method="POST" action="UpdateAction">
        <s:actionerror/>
        <s:textfield name="uname" label="Username" value="#session.LoggedUser.getUsername"/>
        <s:property value="#session.LoggedUser.getUsername()"/>
        <s:password name="password" label="Password"/>
        <s:password name="cPassword" label="Confirm password"/>
        <s:textfield name="fname" label="First name" value="#session.loggeduser.getFname()"/>
        <s:textfield name="lname" label="Last name" value="#session.loggeduser.getLname()"/>
        <s:textfield name="popServer" label="POP server" value="#session.loggeduser.getPopServer()"/>
        <s:textfield name="popUsername" label="POP username" value="#session.loggeduser.getPopUsername()"/>
        <s:password name="popPassword" label="POP password"/>
        <s:textfield name="mobilePhone" label="Mobile phone" value="#session.loggeduser.getMobilePhone()"/>
        <s:textfield name="filter" label="Notification filter" value="#session.loggeduser.getSms()"/>
        <s:checkbox name="sms" label="Enable SMS notification"/>
        <s:submit value="Update"/>
    </s:form>
</body>
```

I want your help, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this

```
<s:textfield name="uname" label="Username" value="#session.LoggedUser.getUsername"/>
```

use this

```
<s:textfield name="uname" label="Username" value='<s:property value="%{#session.loggedUser.getUsername}"/>'/>
```

On a similar note you can do for rest of your fields.

Another thing you are mismatching `LoggedUser` and `loggedUser`, in your Java code key is `loggedUser` and not `LoggedUser`, so in jsp use `loggedUser`.

Off topic:
I don't think you need to use scriptlet in your jsp code.

Answer (score 1):

This tag will generate text input with name "uname" and value "#session.LoggedUser.getUsername".

Your want to read value from the session. Of course, your can read value this way:

```
<s:textfield name="#session.LoggedUser.getUsername" label="Username" value="#session.LoggedUser.getUsername"/>
```

but i don't think that your need input with name "#session.LoggedUser.getUsername" )

So the solution is:

```
<input type="text" name="uname" value="<s:property value="#session.LoggedUser.username"/>"/>
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried to use your solution but it does not work.

Thanx for your time :)

Comment: I think mistake in "#session.LoggedUser.username" it must be "#session.loggedUser.username". Sorry )

Answer (score 1):

On Struts 2.3 works: `value="%{#session.loggedUser.username}"`

Answer (score -1):

This is not working

```
 value="#session.LOGIN.name"
```

This is working

```
 value="%{#session.LOGIN.name}"
```